# Proof that for any $x$ there is a $y$ such that $xy$ is a palindrome

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, decimal-expansion, palindrome

I'm wondering how I would prove

> For any $x$ there exists at least one $y$ such that $xy$ is a palindrome.

For example: $91\cdot 99=9009$.

Comment: Assuming positive integers $x,y$, it's sufficient to disprove this through counter-example -- consider an $x$ such that $x \equiv 0 \bmod 10$.

Comment: Assuming that $x$ is not a multiple of $10$, there's always a way to do this without leading zeroes, I believe. Example: $16$ is a factor of $610016$. (There are smaller examples, of course; it's also a factor of $272$.)

Answer (score 4):

Depending whether you allow leading zeroes (i.e. whether you allow $010$ as a palindrome representation of ten and similar ones), answer is either yes or no.

If you **don't** allow such leading zeroes, there are easy counterexamples (I'm leaving them for you to find).

If you **do** allow them, then the statement is true. It's enough to prove the following:

> For any integer $n>0$ there is a positive multiple of $n$ such that it's decimal expansion has the form $11...100...0$.

(hint to the proof of this: consider numbers $1,11,111,1111,...$ and look at reminders when dividing by $n$. Some two of these will give the same reminder)

Comment: how do you get from that to there being a palindrome?

Comment: @miniparser A string of ones is a palindrome, so if you add equal number of leading and trailing zeroes it still is one.

Answer (score 1):

As Marcus Andrews correctly points out, if leading zeros are disallowed, then trailing zeros are also disallowed, and a palindromic multiple of any $x \ge 1$ with trailing zeros would be impossible.

However this can be addressed (for any radix base $b \ge 2$) either by allowing leading zeros to be used, or by restricting $x$ to be coprime to base $b$.

Suppose first that $x$ is coprime to $b$, so that by [Euler's generalization of Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem):

$$ b^{\varphi(x)} \equiv 1 \bmod{x} $$

where Euler's function $\varphi(x)$ counts the coprime residues mod $x$.

Then $\sum_{k=1}^x b^{(k-1)\varphi(x)}$ is divisible by $x$ (since each of the $x$ summands is congruent to $1 \bmod{x}$) and palindromic when written out in base $b$.

Further, in the case $x$ is not coprime to $b$, if we are allowed to prepend $n$ leading zeros to such an expression as well as $n$ trailing zeros, these may be used to provide a multiple of any factor of $x$ which divides a corresponding power $b^n$.

We have shown that each $x \ge 1$ has a multiple that is expressible in base $b$ (possibly with leading zeros) by **a palindrome consisting solely of zeros and ones**.

**Added:**  @Akiva Weinberger has proposed that leading zeros can be avoided in all cases where $x$ is not a multiple of base $b$.  We show that this is correct.

Let $x=uv$ be factored so that $u$ is the largest divisor of $x$ coprime to $b$, and hence $v$ contains only those prime factors of $x$ that are common to $b$.

If $b$ does not divide $x$, then $b$ does not $v$.  However $v$ divides some sufficiently large power $b^n$, while the base $b$ representation of $v$ does not have a trailing zero.  Let $w$ be the result of reversing the base $b$ representation of $v$, and thus $wb^n + v$ is a multiple of $v$ whose base $b$ representation is a palindrome.

Modify the construction $\sum_{k=1}^u b^{M\cdot (k-1)\varphi(u)}$ for a base $b$ palindrome divisible by $u$, to include an integer parameter $M \ge 1$.  Choose $M$ sufficiently large that $b^{M\cdot \varphi(u)} \gt wb^n + v$.

Then the spacing between 1's in the base $b$ representation of $\sum_{k=1}^u b^{M\cdot (k-1)\varphi(u)}$ is sufficiently wide that:

$$ \left( \sum_{k=1}^u b^{M\cdot (k-1)\varphi(u)} \right) (wb^n + v) $$

is a palindrome, has no trailing zero, and is divisible by $x=uv$.